# Text in .write gets cut off

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to make a program that will create a LaTex file (.tex) with a preamble in it, and sooner some sections. I have defined my function *thepreamble(title,subject)* such that the inputs will be created in the string, which is seen below in my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io
def thepreamble(title, subject):
    global preamble
    preamble = r'''\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breaklinks, colorlinks=true,linkcolor=NavyBlue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=Blue, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzrput}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}


\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{NavyBlue}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}

\newcommand{\dl}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}




\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{30ex}
{\fontsize{38}{0}\selectfont \bfseries  \fontfamily{put}\selectfont \color{NavyBlue} '''+ str(title)+'''} \\
[3ex]
{\fontsize{18}{0}\selectfont \bfseries  \fontfamily{put}\selectfont \color{NavyBlue}  ('''+str(subject)+ ''')}\\
[14ex]
{ \fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont Casper Juul Lorentzen} \\
[3ex]
{\large \scshape 1.z} \\
[2ex]
{\large \scshape 2018}\\
\vspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{C:/LaTeX/Next.png} \\
[4mm]
\small{\bfseries Albertslund Gymnasium \& HF} \\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Indhold \vspace{3ex}}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
    '''
    return preamble




def sections(numsec, numsubsec):
    numbers = []
    numbers.extend(numsubsec)
    global tasks
    tasks = []

    print("") 
    #Brug prÃ¦fikset 'r' foran unicodes 
    print("")
    for n,i in zip(range(1, numsec+1),range(0,numsec)):
        print("")
        opgaver = "\section{Opgave "+str(n)+"}"
        print(opgaver)
        print("")
        tasks.append(opgaver)
        for x in range(int(numsubsec[i])):
            print("\subsection{}")
            print("")

    return tasks
def runprogram():
    encoding ='utf8'
    titlefile = input("Title (file): ")
    title = input("Title of document: ")
    subject = input("Subject: ")
    numsec = int(input("How many sections? "))
    filename = "C:\\Users\\Casper\\Documents\\LaTeX\\fire.tex"
    while True:
        numsubsec = input("How many subsections?")
        while len(numsubsec) !=numsec:
            print("")
            numsubsec =input("Error; input must be of "+ str(numsec) + " digits ")
        try:
            with io.open(filename.replace('fire.tex',titlefile+".tex"), 'w', encoding=encoding) as f:
                f.write(unicode_thepreamble(title, subject))
                f.close()

            #sections(numsec, numsubsec)
            break
        except:
            print("Error")



runprogram()
```

Whenever I run the program, it creates a new .tex file with the name of

```
titlefile = input("Title (file): ")
```

As you can see, i have defined *preamble* as a text with unicode characters in it. And when I run the program, it writes almost everything of the preamble string in the tex document, but it cuts some of it off and creates weird symbol, like this:
[tex document created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlrLg.png)

I named the title 'stackoverflow' and the subject 'python problem', and that works fine. But what ought to be '\renewcommand' is in the document '     enewcommand'. I do not know how to fix this. I just want precisely what my preamble strings says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge your title and subject into the string you have to make the second piece raw again

```
r''' bla bla '''+ str(title) + r''' bla bla'''
```

The second "r" is missing, twice in your example.

You should consider merging using `str.format()`.

Comment: I have added and 'r' after str(title) and str(subject), but when I run the code, it says 'error'
'How many subsections?'
As a consequence of my while loop.

Comment: The code is buggy and I was not sure how this part should work, but I changed *numsubsec = [int(input("How many subsections?"))]* so that it ran through.

Comment: Nevermind! This works. Worked in eclipse and forgot to save. Thanks.

Comment: can you 1) provide an example with format, and also explain why _not_ adding the raw prefix causes an issue?

Comment: I just wanted say that the error of missing the second "r" in *r'\documentclass ' + str("X") + r'\documentclass'* could have been avoided when using *r'\documentclass {}\documentclass'.format("X")*. I assume that it is also more efficient.